# A @ContainedIn entity does not get indexed automatically, when it gets saved to the DB

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search to update a Lucene index automatically, every time a new Photo entity comes in. When photo data gets saved or edited, it gets automatically in the index pretty quickly. When a comment is added, however, it never gets in. And that it is exactly what the `@IndexedEmbedded/@ContainedIn` should do, right?

My code is roughly the following one:

```
@Indexed(index="/indexes/photo.index")
@Entity
public class Photo {

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="photo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Comment> comments;

}

@Indexed(index="indexes/comment.index")
@Entity
public class Comment {

    @ContainedIn
    @ManyToOne
    public Photo photo;

    @Field
    public String text;
}
```

I am using the following lib versions:

```
hibernate-search-3.4.0.Final
lucene-core-3.6.0
lucene-analyzers-3.1.0
```

NOTE: For those wh jump right away, saying that I messed up the order of those two annotations, I'll say I tried the other way around, too. Doesn't work.

Comment: Could you show the code the adds the comment? Do you add it to the list on photo and then save the photo?

Answer (score 0):

Version 3.4.0.Final was the first one including a dirty-checking optimisation, this got more stable in later versions. Could you try setting the Hibernate configuration property

```
hibernate.search.enable_dirty_check=false
```

to make sure that such optimisations are not affecting you.

Also, use the Lucene version on which this release was designed for or you could get in trouble with just anything:

```
lucene-core-3.1.0
lucene-analyzers-3.1.0
```